# Update dict's value without too many copies of items

Tags: python

I have the following data of job details,
one of them is

```
   job_detail = {
        "company": "abc company recruit",
        "job_title": "python developer",
        "job_request": "20k-40k /Delhi / 3-5years / Bachelor / Full-time",
        "job_tags": "Big Data\nSoftware Development",
        "pub_date": "10:19  published from network",
}
```

I tried to extract and format it with the following code:

```
job_detail["company"] = job_detail["company"].replace("recruit", "").strip()
job_detail["job_title"] = job_detail["job_title"].strip()
job_request = [jr.strip() for jr in job_detail["job_request"].split("/")]
salary, location, experience, education, time = job_request
job_detail['salary'] = salary
job_detail['location'] = location
job_detail['experience'] = experience
job_detail["education"] = education
job_detail['time'] = time
job_detail["job_tags"] = job_detail["job_tags"].replace("\n", ",")
job_detail['pub_date'] = re.search(r"\w+", job_detail["pub_date"]).group()
```

Run it an come by

```
In [81]: job_detail
Out[81]: 
{'company': 'abc company',
 'job_title': 'python developer',
 'job_request': '20k-40k /Delhi / 3-5years / Bachelor / Full-time',
 'job_tags': 'Big Data,Software Development',
 'pub_date': '10',
 'salary': '20k-40k',
 'location': 'Delhi',
 'experience': '3-5years',
 'education': 'Bachelor',
 'time': 'Full-time'}
```

I get the desired data with too many typing of "job_details", and every item should be copied on every line.

How could I solve the problem in an elegant way?

Comment: This code is functional, so may be better off on [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Working code. Wanting to make it better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211790/305121)-questions belong to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` to create key,value pairs and use `dict.update` to update the dict

```
>>> keys=["salary", "location", "experience", "education", "time"]
>>> pairs = zip(keys, map(str.strip, job_detail["job_request"].split("/")))
>>> job_detail.update(pairs)
>>> pprint(job_detail)
{'company': 'abc company recruit',
 'education': 'Bachelor',
 'experience': '3-5years',
 'job_request': '20k-40k /Delhi / 3-5years / Bachelor / Full-time',
 'job_tags': 'Big Data\nSoftware Development',
 'job_title': 'python developer',
 'location': 'Delhi',
 'pub_date': '10:19  published from network',
 'salary': '20k-40k',
 'time': 'Full-time'}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simpler ones you can try something like this

```
job_detail = {
    "company": "abc company recruit",
    "job_title": "python developer",
    "job_request": "20k-40k /Delhi / 3-5years / Bachelor / Full-time",
    "job_tags": "Big Data\nSoftware Development",
    "pub_date": "10:19  published from network",
}
salary, location, experience, education, time1 = 0,0,0,0,0
keys=["salary", "location", "experience", "education", "time1"]
for key in keys:
    job_detail[key]=eval(key)
```